# How move the portion of the background task to the main thread? (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making an example for sending push notifications to Android with Firebase.

The class that receives the messages is the following:

```js
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        String message;
            message = "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom();
            message += "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        MainActivity.updateMessage(message);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.updateMessage(message); try to place the text that has arrived in a TextView in the main activity but I get the following error message:

**“Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”**

I have researched a bit and the explanation is that the task (I imagine the reception) should go in the main thread:

```js
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Stuff that updates the UI

    }
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to place the class in the prinicpal thread.

Is there another way to pass that message to the main activity?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The best way is using BroadcastReceiver to send update message to your activity. Or, you can use any kind of event bus libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a message from a service to activity, the easy way is using `BroadcastReceiver` API.

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
            // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
            // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
            // message, here is where that should be initiated.
            String message;
            message = "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom();
            message += "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            // Send the message to your activity.
            Intent intent = new Intent("FisebaseMessage");
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((mMessageReceiver),
                new IntentFilter("FisebaseMessage")
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get message that sent from the service
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

            // Update message in the activity
            updateMessage(message);
        }
    };

    private void updateMessage(String message) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually two different questions implied in this question.  One is:

> How do I move work from a background thread to the main thread?

and

> How do a get manipulate the currently running activity from the context of a service?

It appears you've got some solution for the second question, but I suspect it's not the most robust solution (using static variables within the activity to keep track of an instance of that activity).  Regardless, let's just imagine that's OK (but it's probably going to cause you problems later).

If you're happy with the way that you're tracking instances of MainActivity, you can move work from the messaging service's background thread to the main thread by using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler):

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // code here will run on the main thread
    }
});
```

If you want a more robust solution for an activity to receive background messages, consider using an event bus, or RxJava, or Android architecture components LiveData to relay the message.